# How to restrict access to certain route by port with Symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

Our webserver is listening 80 and 8080 ports, and I want a specific route to be available only through port 8080, but to deny access to all users that attempt to access that route using port 80.

I have some routes in my `routes.yaml`

```
testing-logging:
  path: /testing/logging
  controller: Test\Infrastructure\API\HTTP\Technical\LoggingController::handle
  methods: [GET]

healthcheck:
  path: /healthcheck
  controller: Test\API\HTTP\Technical\HealthcheckController::handle
  methods: [GET]
```

There are a little more routes of course, but they are like these ones.

It's a microservice, so there are no any users.

I want to restrict access for some routes by custom port. Of course, others routes must work as before with standard port.

I tried to use security:

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory: { memory: null }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            security: true
            anonymous: ~
            methods: [POST]
        main:
            anonymous: lazy
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/healthcheck, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, port: 8080 }
```

Comment: Yes. Im actually writing functional tests for route.

Comment: Nah, i'm looking for any way to do restriction by port. I did not find anything more suitable for my purpose, but security package.

Comment: Maybe something wrong with above configuration or with something else - i just want to have AccessDeniedException  or some error because i use 80 port.

Comment: I want RequestMatcher give me an Exception. I don't know why not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another `access_control` rule for port 80.

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/healthcheck, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, port: 8080 }
        - { path: ^/healthcheck, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, port: 80 }
```

Since you do not have any authentication mechanism, no user will have `ROLE_ADMIN`. Thus, any user attempting to access `^/healthcheck` on port 80 will have their access denied.

Comment: Yeah, but i want to fail at first.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand you, Skarlet. What do you mean "at first"? The above will deny requests on port 80, but allow requests on port 8080. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Probably, there something wrong with configuration: i changed method, run docker container with service (the ports are 80 and 8080), open link in chrome  and it still work.
Maybe this is the reason why access_control does not work for me.

Comment: The above configuration is tested @Scarlet. Any request coming on port `80` will be denied, and any request coming on port `8080` will be served.

Comment: I don't have access to server configuration.
Okay, let's make it simpler. No webserver. 
I use only application and functional test.

Comment: okay. I guess i should try it with local server. Maybe it can not be tested this way.

Comment: I've just tested it running once `bin/console server:run 127.0.0.1:8001` and `bin/console server:run 127.0.0.1:8000` (my rules are set for these ports). Try to access the same URL on each run, once I'm in, the other time "access denied".